# Log4j with Flume Appenders

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to deploy liferay instance in two nodes where I am using tomcat as application server. Here I am using Flume for global logging purpose. I was able to deploy the liferay instance on one node and its working properly, but when I try to deploy on another node its being throwing the following errors at different places:

> ERROR Could not create FlumePersistentManager
>   com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentLockedException: (JE 5.0.73) /app/flume
>   The environment cannot be locked for single writer access. ENV_LOCKED:
>   The je.lck file could not be locked. Environment is invalid and must
>   be closed.,
>
> ERROR Unable to invoke method createAppender in class
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.flume.appender.FlumeAppender for element
>   Flume java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

Here is my logging configuration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<configuration packages="com.intuit.ifs.globallogging" status="trace" name="Flume">
    <MarkerFilter marker="EVENT" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
    <appenders>
        <Flume name="flume" alwaysWriteExceptions="false" mdcPrefix="ReqCtx_" type="Persistent" compress="true" dataDir="/app/flume">
            <mdcExcludes>company</mdcExcludes>
            <Agent host="my machine name" port="8800" />
            <Agent host="my machine name" port="8800" />
            <RFC5424Layout enterpriseNumber="12293" includeMDC="true" mdcId="RequestContext" appName="AdminPlatform" />
            <property name="keyProvider">IFSKeyProvider</property>
        </Flume>
        <Console name="console">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class{36}:%L %M - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="rollingFile" fileName="${catalina.base}/logs/glLogging.log" filePattern="${catalina.base}/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/glLogging-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <Rewrite name="eventLogger" ignoreExceptions="false">
            <appender-ref ref="flume" />
        </Rewrite>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <logger name="EventLogger" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="eventLogger" />
        </logger>
        <root level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="rollingFile" />
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to delete `je.lck` file, but no use.

Can you please help me on this if you faced this issue before?

Comment: My log4j-flume.log file: